# How do I get given value is Integer Or String

Tags: java, string, object, integer, instance

I am trying to find solution of my problem. And my problem is that I am getting a parameter value named `"key"` and its data-type is `Object`. Before starting of any kind of use of this `key` I wanna check first is it `Integer` or `String` and any kind of `data-type`(main aim is to check between `Integer` & `String`).

I already try google but i got nothing  useful.

please provide some solution .

Many many thanks in advance.

**Example**

```
if(key is Integer){
  //do something here
}else{
  // do something here
}
```

Comment: The operator is called `instanceof` in Java.

Comment: You can use `Interger.parse()` or `regex` to find out if it is an Integer.

Comment: Thanku guyzz Its was help full , i am gonna trying this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for Integer -

```
if(key instanceof Integer){
 //Integer
}
```

And for String -

```
if(key instanceof String){
 //String
}
```

Or you may use `key.getClass()`

Answer (score 2):

I use as below

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.invoke(1);
    test.invoke("something");

}
public void invoke(Object obj) {
    if (obj != null) {
        if (obj.getClass() == Integer.class) {
            System.out.println("It is integer !");
        }
        else if (obj.getClass() == String.class) {
            System.out.println("It is String !");
        }
    }
}
```

Output

> It is integer !
>
> It is String !

Answer (score 0):

You can try using instatnceOf operator. It will tell you if the key is of Integer type or not.

```
if(key instanceOf Integer)
 {
    //key is Integer type
 }
```